# Azure search search.in returning error

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I am trying to use azure search with search.in but it returns with following error

---

{
    "error": {
        "code": "",
        "message": "Invalid expression: Unsupported function call: search.in. This function is not supported in this API version.\r\nParameter name: $filter"
    }
}

---

api-version is 2016-09-01

but it works with api-version=2015-02-28-Preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are rolling out support for `search.in` in the GA API version `2016-09-01` in the next few days. For now, please use the preview API version `2016-09-01-Preview`.